# How do I add A Div around each WordPress post image ?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to add a div around every image that is posted on my wordpress blog post. 
How can I do it?

(For the curious ones, I'm attempting to pop out some share buttons whenever a user hovers over an image).

Comment: How many existing posts do you have, and how many images on each post roughly? The simplist way could be to literally handcode `<div class='yourClass'></div>` around each image in each of your posts. Is that a moderately easy task?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following snippet of code into your functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'wp_image_wrap_init', 10, 8 );    
    function wp_image_wrap_init( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt ) {
    return '<div id="wp-image-wrap-'. $id .'" class="wp-image-wrap">'. $html .'</div>';
}
```

Comment: It didn't change anything with my image.

Comment: My code sorted out to be much longer btw 
http://jsfiddle.net/vzurqnvo/

Comment: I tested this code, and should work  based on default Wordpress? This will wrap all default post images with a div. If the images are generated by custom functions this may not work.

Comment: Default wordpress, twentyfourteen. 
I'm working with this and it's kinda ok
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36000/wrap-all-post-images-inside-a-div-element 

I'll update :)

Comment: Well, It worked. 
I just have a Problem with the code, I want to share the existing page, so I use <?php the_permalink(); ?> in the code, when it's in "<?php the_permalink(); ?>" 
what can I do with this issue?

Comment: `<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=&url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="img-twitter" title="Share on Twitter"></a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>?" title="Share on Facebook" onclick="window.open(this.href, \'newwin\', \'width=500, height=200\'); return false;" class="img-facebook"></a>
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="img-google" title="Share on Google"></a>
`

Comment: I posted the final answer :) 
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: took me a while to figure that out but it only works for newly inserted images, not images that are already in a post.

Answer (score 0):

So this solved everything :) ! 
Thank you guys for your help here. I hope it will be useful to others.

```
function breezer_addDivToImage( $content ) {
   // A regular expression of what to look for.
   $pattern = '/(<img([^>]*)>)/i';
   // What to replace it with. $1 refers to the content in the first 'capture group', in parentheses above
   $the_url = the_permalink();
   $replacement = '<div class="imgWrap"> 
                        $1
                        <div class="imgDescription">
                                            <div class="theShareLinks">
                                                <img src="http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/dfc2.png" />
                                                <a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=&url='.get_the_permalink() .'" class="img-twitter" title="Share on Twitter" target="_blank"></a>
                                                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='.get_the_permalink() .'?" class="img-facebook" title="Share on Facebook" target="_blank" onclick="window.open(this.href, \'newwin\', \'width=500, height=200\'); return false;" ></a>
                                                <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url='.get_the_permalink() .'" class="img-google" title="Share on Google" target="_blank"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                    </div>';

   // run preg_replace() on the $content
   $content = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $content );

   // return the processed content
   return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'breezer_addDivToImage' );
```

Comment: and I opened this post for the other issue of the links inside the " and '. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422157/how-to-use-the-permalink-on-wordpress-when-its-wrapped-with-or

if someone is interested..

Answer (score -2):

If it's as simple as you make seem, just switch to the text editor, or disable the visual editor, and add the div around every image you insert. Give them all the same class, and then add your style for that class in your stylesheet.

-- Or, if you want to apply this to all kinds of pages on your Wordpress installation (Pages, Posts, Archives, Categories etc): --

Dive into the FTP, and start having a look in your themes folders and files.

You've got different pages for different views. attachment.php, page.php etc. Depending on which view you want to change, these files will include a line that may look similar to this:

```
<p class="attachment">
    <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $post->ID ); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="attachment">
        <img src="<?php echo $att_image[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $att_image[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $att_image[2]; ?>" class="attachment-medium" alt="<?php $post->post_excerpt; ?>" />
    </a>
</p>
```

Or anywhere that mentions

```
<img src="<?php echo $att_image[0]; ?>" />
```

Just add a div around that, and add a styling rule in your stylesheet.

Comment: I don't think that is what he's asking.  He wants a `div` wrapped around any image added to a post, not on the attachment page.

Comment: That's why I said "Depending on which view you want to change"

Comment: Right, but there isn't a view for an inline image in a post.

Comment: Actually he could apple the CSS literally to the img tag just within posts, but obviously that could have its own issues.